# How to implement map that associates a name with void function in C?

Tags: c, functional-programming, sicp

After reading Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs (SICP) I decided to find a way to implement some of these functional programming techniques using C.  I tried to write a program that makes a pair whose first argument is a name of the function and second arg is any function that takes one arg and returns one arg.  Using implementation below I was expecting to see
an output like:

```
fact(7) = 5040
fib(7) = 13
```

but instead I am getting

```
fact(7) = 5040
fib(7) = 0
```

along with warnings

```
$ cc map.c
map.c: In function ‘main’:
map.c:41:17: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   maps[0].f_ptr = &fact;
                 ^
map.c:43:17: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   maps[1].f_ptr = &fib;
                 ^
map.c:47:7: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘maps[i].f_ptr’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
       ans = (int) maps[i].f_ptr((int) num);
       ^
map.c:47:7: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
map.c:47:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
       ans = (int) maps[i].f_ptr((int) num);
             ^
map.c:52:7: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘maps[i].f_ptr’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
       ans2 = (int) maps[i].f_ptr((int) num);
       ^
map.c:52:7: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
map.c:52:14: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
       ans2 = (int) maps[i].f_ptr((int) num);
```

during compilation. Looking at the code I don't see the problem but then again I haven't used C in quite some time. Is there a better way to implement such a construct and why is fib(7) printing a 0 instead of 13?

Here's my code:

```
struct Map
{
  char* name;
  void* (*f_ptr)(void*);
};

int fact(int a) {
    if (a == 0)
      return 0;
    if (a == 1)
      return 1;
    return a * fact (a-1);
}

int fib(int a) {
  if (a == 0)
    return 0;
  if (a == 1)
    return 1;
  return fib(a-1) + fib(a-2);
}

int findFunc (char* str, struct Map map)
{
  if (map.name == str)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  int ans = 0;
  int ans2 = 0;
  int num = 7;

  struct Map maps[2];
  maps[0].name = "fact";
  maps[0].f_ptr = &fact;
  maps[1].name = "fib";
  maps[1].f_ptr = &fib;

  for (i; i < (sizeof(maps)/sizeof(maps[0])); i++) {
    if (findFunc("fact", maps[i]))
      ans = (int) maps[i].f_ptr((int) num);
  }

  for (i; i < (sizeof(maps)/sizeof(maps[0])); i++) {
    if (findFunc("fib", maps[i]))
      ans2 = (int) maps[i].f_ptr((int) num);
  }

  printf("fact(%d) = %d\n", num, ans);
  printf("fib(%d) = %d", num, ans2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `void* (*f_ptr)(void*);` define `int (*f_ptr)(int);`.

Comment: @alk As I indicated above, the reason I want to use void* is so I can allow functions of different types.

Comment: Using `void*(*)(void*)` only allows you to use functions taking *one pointer value* and returning a pointer value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### String comparisons

This is not how you do string comparison in C.

```
if (map.name == str)
```

This is how you do string comparison in C.

```
if (0 == strcmp(map.name, str))
```

Because strings in C are just pointers to characters, `map.name == str` checks if `map.name` and `str` are identical pointers (point to the same block of memory), not whether what they point to is the same.

### for loops

Your code is probably reporting `fib(7) = 0` because it's failing to find fib. One possible culprit is the string comparison issue I mentioned. However, your `for` loop syntax is also odd:

```
for (i; i < (sizeof(maps)/sizeof(maps[0])); i++) {
```

You don't set `i` to anything, so this means, "Starting from wherever i happens to be, do the following..."

To loop over all of maps, use this:

```
for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(maps)/sizeof(maps[0])); i++) {
```

### type warnings

As @alk said in a comment, the reason you're getting all of those warnings is because you've declared a function type of `void* (*f_ptr)(void*);`, even though your functions are `int (*)(int)`. If you want to keep using `void*` to allow different types, and you're careful enough with your types to make this work, then you can add casts to silence the warnings.

```
maps[0].f_ptr = (void *(*)(void*)) &fact;
ans2 = (int) maps[i].f_ptr((void*) num);
```

Etc.

### Better implementations?

A "real" implementation of mapping functions to names would use a hash table, instead of linearly searching for matching names.  Implementing a hash table in C would add complexity and may not be worth it for this exercise.

Comment: Comparing the pointers of string literals *might* work, but they are not guaranteed to have only one instance of the same string.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind, but that doesn't change the output or the error messages.

Answer (score 2):

> but instead I am getting
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> fib(7) = 0
> ```

The code misses to initialise `i` to `0` for the 2nd  `for`-loop.

Comment: Yes don't be lazy with a `for` loop. If you want to continue a previous loop you can write `(for i=i; ...)` and the compiler will do the right thing.

Comment: Thanks, that's it.  As for the void* is there a way to avoid all these warnings if I want to allow functions of different types?

Comment: @TarBall: "*avoid all these warnings*" Only by (dirty) casting, probably invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: Better use C++ for such approaches.

Comment: @alk I'm sorry if this is a silly question but I am not familiar with the term dirty casting, would you care to elaborate?

Comment: The "dirty" is just a hint to not do it. @TarBall

Comment: Thank you alk, you got an eye like a hawk.

Comment: @TarBall - You can create arbitrarily complicated data structures in C, so you technically can allow functions of different types and different numbers of arguments. See [GLib's](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/) variants and tuples for an example. It would be very ugly, though; like alk says, a higher-level language like C++ would be much easier.

Comment: @JoshKelley The reason I chose C is because I haven't used it in a while and wanted to write a couple of simple programs as a refresher, but thanks for the GLib's variants link, it looks interesting.